# Plot summarized data using qplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to cross-classify and plot `bal` using `qplot` facets:

```
> str(bal)
'data.frame':   2096 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ fips     : chr  "24510" "24510" "24510" "24510" ...
 $ SCC      : chr  "10100601" "10200601" "10200602" "30100699" ...
 $ Pollutant: chr  "PM25-PRI" "PM25-PRI" "PM25-PRI" "PM25-PRI" ...
 $ Emissions: num  6.53 78.88 0.92 10.38 10.86 ...
 $ type     : chr  "POINT" "POINT" "POINT" "POINT" ...
 $ year     : int  1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 ...
```

I'm interested in the two classifiers `year` and `type`:

```
> levels(factor(bal$year))
[1] "1999" "2002" "2005" "2008"
> levels(factor(bal$type))
[1] "NON-ROAD" "NONPOINT" "ON-ROAD"  "POINT"
```

I get it so far, that I can plot the distribution of `Emissions` cross-classified by year and type:
[image]
What I'm unable to do is to plot the `sum` of the distributions of each year, which I however am able to compute:

```
> tapply(bal$Emissions, list(bal$year, bal$type), sum)
      NON-ROAD NONPOINT   ON-ROAD     POINT
1999 522.94000 2107.625 346.82000  296.7950
2002 240.84692 1509.500 134.30882  569.2600
2005 248.93369 1509.500 130.43038 1202.4900
2008  55.82356 1373.207  88.27546  344.9752
```

My guess was something along the lines of

```
> qplot(bal$year, tapply(bal$Emissions, list(bal$year, bal$type), sum), 
        data=bal, facets= . ~ type)
Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the
dataProblems:tapply(bal$Emissions, list(bal$year, bal$type), sum)
```

but I dont get what `R` is telling me there.

How can I plot this matrix using `qplot`?

Comment: a `dput(bal)` would help make this reproducible.

Comment: Happily find it here: [link](http://pastebin.com/aiVKsUyz)

Answer (score 2):

You dan do that using `ggplot` with either

```
qplot(year, Emissions, data=bal, 
    stat="summary", fun.y="sum",
    facets= .~type
)
```

or

```
ggplot(bal) +
    aes(year, Emissions) +
    stat_summary(fun.y="sum",geom="point") + 
    facet_grid(.~type)
```

Both should give you the following plot which seems to match up well to your summary data.

[image: plot with summarized data]

Comment: From the `?help` section: "`Usage:
qplot(x, y = NULL, ..., data, facets = NULL,
margins = FALSE, geom = "auto", stat = list(NULL),
position = list(NULL), xlim = c(NA, NA),
ylim = c(NA, NA), log = "", main = NULL,
xlab = deparse(substitute(x)),
ylab = deparse(substitute(y)), asp = NA)`
"
I would never have figured that `fun.y` can be an argument. How can I know what `...` means?

Comment: Well, with a function like `qplot` it's pretty hard to know what `...` will mean. But generally that means that the top level function will pass on any additional parameters to other functions it calls. Since we are using `stat="summary"`, we can assume that `qplot` is calling `stat_summary` and will pass the `fun.y` parameter along. I don't think this is very clear and I personally think one of the major weaknesses of `ggplot2` is the documentation.

Comment: So true. Then how did you know what kind of parameter values are possible for `stat`? `summary` is nowhere in the help page for `qplot`.

Comment: @TMOTTM Intuition, i guess. I know that doesn't help you. See if you can find the `ggplot2` book at a local library. That might help get you oriented.